# Mouseleave mouseout and focus

Tags: jquery

I would like some confirmation of my thinking so that I may better understand inconsistencies that I experience.

Mouseleave and mouseenter should be used in conjunction with each other as should mouseout and mouseover. Mixing say Mouseleave and mouseover is bad practice.

Mouseleave was originally for IE only jquery normalises mouseleave / mouseenter so that it can be used cross browser

The main difference between mouseleave and mouseout is that mouseleave is triggered when exiting the parent (which is what I want) where as mouseout is triggered when moving between siblings within a parent as well as when leaving the parent (This is what I do not want).

So my problem is inconsistent behaviour. When using mouseleave I find that the script may or may not action the code bound to the event.

Call me a fool by all means. But I observed that if I moused out to the side or to the bottom of the parent #send_To mouseleave was triggered. If I moused out of the top it did not.

So I found that by setting focus elsewhere this behaviour was removed. However it is still not completely consistent. And on some occasions regardless of which way you exit the event is not triggered. Again please feel free to laugh but I find that moving the mouse rapidly is more likely to trigger the event than if I move it slowly. I can't think of any valid sensible reason for this I am merely reporting what I find.

I would like to understand why I am seeing this behaviour which doesn't make any sense to me.

```
$("#send_To").bind("mouseleave",
    function(event){
        $("#send_To").css("display","none");
        $("#message").focus();        // added this seems to improve behaviour
    }
);
```

Please could someone advise. Is this because jquery is normalizing. Is there a cast iron method of ensuring that a mouseleave event is triggered.

Comment: Hang on how does that help? I understood that on bound events that are added to the script dynamically. I.e. the bind is not possible on document ready. Quite happy to try that but would like to understand why that might work.

Comment: `mouseleave` is not triggered when exiting the parent. It is triggered when exiting the element itself.

Comment: @Asad ok yes I see that. I mis-phrased my description. Perhaps I should say move out To the parent. I.e. it should not trigger whilst moving inside the element.

Comment: Ok I have tried using .on instead of .bind. Sadly the inconsistent behaviour persists.

Comment: Could we get a bit of HTML? And maybe even a jsfiddle that reproduces the bug? Because it works where I test